# Trying to prevent user from going back to previous page after logout is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

We have a login.php page, a logout.php page and a protected page with this snippet:

```
<?php
 $token = $_GET['token'];
  $user = $_GET['user'];

// Check if logged-in.
if(!$_SESSION["$user"])
{
    //Do not show protected data, redirect to login if user has logged out.
    header('default: login.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
..
...
```

When I click the logout link, I am redirected to login.php page. This is fine.

However, when I click the back button, I am taken back to the prevoius page and I am trying to prevent that from happening.

Isn't the page protected enough?

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
<?php
 //start the session session_start();
 //check to make sure the session variable is registered
 if(session_is_registered('username'))
{
//session variable is registered, the user is ready to logout
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}
Else
{
 //the session variable isn't registered, the user shouldn't even be on this page
 header( "Location: default.php?status=loggedout");
}
 ?>
```

Login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<title>Service Request</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
<link href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/boxformats.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>

 <div id="tabs">

<div>
     <br />   <br />
      <br />
       <?php
         if(!empty($_GET['status'])){
                echo '<div align=center><font color=firebrick>You have been logged out!</font><br><br>Log in again or close browser.</div>';
         }
       ?>
       <br />
        <br />
      <br />
      <form id="FormToValidate">
        <table>
         <tr>

           <td nowrap>
                   <div class="input text">
              <label><strong>UserName:</strong></label>
              <input  maxlength="40" class="required" name="user" id="user" size="20" placeholder="Enter username!" type="text" title="Please enter a username." tabindex="2" value="" style="width:400px;color:#999;font-size:9pt;height:20px;" />
            </div>
          </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td nowrap>
               <div class="input text">
                <label><strong>Password:</strong></label>
                <input  maxlength="40" class="required" name="pass" id="pass" size="20" placeholder="Enter password!" type="password" tabindex="3" title="Please enter a password." value="" style="width:400px;color:#999;font-size:9pt;height:20px;" />
               </div>
              </td>

         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td></td>
              <td>
              <div class="buttonSubmit">
              <input type="button" id="btnValidate" style="width:80px; margin-left:-152px;background-color:#fff;" value="Log In" />
             </div><br clear="all"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btnValidate").click(function() {

// Creating variables to hold data from textboxes

var uname = $("#user").val();
var upass = $("#pass").val();

$.post("validate.php",
  { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: uname,Password: upass }) })
    .done(function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        switch(result.Status) {
            case 0:
                //login successful
                tokenVal = result.Value.Token;
                location.href = protectedpage.php?token="+tokenVal+ "&user=" + uname;
                break;

            case 2:
                //invalid login
                alert(result.Message);
                break;
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("The AJAX request failed!");
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html
```

Comment: please show your logout.php script.  its very hard to see what your doing / not doing without appropriate code. we're not mind readers you  know.

Comment: Are you closing your session in the logout script?

Comment: @Nicolas, RaggaMuffin-420, please see my logout script above. Thank you.

Comment: Try, `session_unlink();` above session_unset

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
// Check if logged-in.
if(!isset($_SESSION[$user]))
{

    header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use if(!isset($_SESSION[$user])) first, to prevent errors?

Comment: @BaileyHerbert it will prevent warnings, but undefined indexes in PHP return NULL, so !$_SESSION[$user] is valid.

Comment: Yes, I know that @RaggaMuffin-420, but that wan't the only thing I changed with this post.

Comment: @RossWilson, when I tried your solution, I am no longer allowed to login into this protected page.

For instance, I open up the login screen, enter username/password, click Validate and the page just blinks and remains in login screen.

Nicola, trying session_unlink(); didn't make any difference as I am still getting to this page when I click the browser back button.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh You don't actually want this code in your login.php file, you should only have it on the pages that you want protecting (login.php should be publicly accessable).

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420, yeah sorry about that, dude! :p I had changed the header though. :)

Comment: @ChidiOkeh Does the login form post back to the login.php? In fact would you be able to update your question with your entire login.php?

Comment: @RossWilson, I have posted login.php page.

As you can see, if user is successfully authenticated, she or he is redirected to protectedpage.php.

The goal now is when the user logouts out, to not allow user back to the protected page until he or she relogs in.
Thanks alot.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh  Well you need to put the above code on every protected page. Then when they want to logout unset the session data and use the above code again.

Comment: @RossWilson, this solution is not working. I can't even log in.

I have it on every protected page but I click login, it keeps me out before I even log in.

If I remove your solution from every protected page, I can log in successfully.

Comment: Is the page where you're setting the `$_SESSION` data for the user a protected page?